# C# создание соединения с donationalerts с помощью сокетов

Tags: c#, visual-studio, сокет, socket.io

Моя цель получить посредством сокетов информацию о поступающем донате: имя, сумма

В сети имеется следующая [статья](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/109444/) где кратко описано взаимодействие с donationalerts на JavaScript

Ниже код из статьи

```
var socket = io("socket.donationalerts.ru:3001");
socket.emit('add-user', {token: "Ваш токен", type: "minor"});
socket.on('donation', function(msg){
  // Ваша функция, обрабатывающая донат
});
```

Код пытаяюсь преобразовать под C#
Для взаимодействия используется библиотека [SocketIO4Net.Client](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=socketio4net)

Однако не знаю как преобразовать следующую часть кода `{ token: "my-token", type: "minor"}` в тип dynamic? Метод `Emit` на вход принимает `(string eventName, dynamic payload)` , как фигурные скобки превратить в `dynamic`? Имеется предположение что это JSON

```
        socket = new Client("socket.donationalerts.ru:3001");
        socket.Emit("add-user", { token: "12345", type: "minor"});
        socket.On("donation", (data) =>
        {
            // Ваша функция, обрабатывающая донат
            var test = data;
        });
```

Comment: Это Typle, unnamed struct, VS какой версии?

Comment: Но на секундочку, в статье используется JavaScript, в `C#` это копи-пастой не вставить.

Comment: @NewView ох, вы правы, моя невнимательность

Answer (score 2):

Тот код который вы скопировали является кодом `JavaScript`, так объявить структуру в `C#` не выйдет. Для сериализации надо подготовить собственную структуру, хотя можно использовать тип `Typle`, но это тема для отдельного вопроса.

Пример структуры:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestNameSpace
{
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public class MyRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty("token")]
        public string MyToken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string MyType { get; set; }

        public string ToJsonString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
        public static MyRequest Deserialize(string jsonString)
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyRequest>(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно **финальный** код:

```
socket.On("connect", (fn) =>
{
   MyRequest mr = new MyRequest() 
     { MyToken = "12345", MyType = "minor"};

   socket.Emit("add-user", mr);
});
socket.On("update", (data) =>
{
     MyResponse mrs = data.Json.GetFirstArgAs<MyResponse>();
     Console.WriteLine("Type:   {0}\r\n", mrs.MyField);
 });
 socket.Connect();
```

Comment: Сделал, компилируется, однако реакции на события нет :( Можете подсказать какой либо способ для проверки кода, в плане может ли он получить сообщение хоть с какого нибудь сервера?

Comment: Там синтаксис дерева событий принципиально другой, попробуйте повторить оригинальный пример со своими параметрами, я не в курсе какое апи по названиям эвентов у этого ресурса. Сейчас поправлю часть отправки, в моем примере, остальное сами..